# In Huxtable R package, condense row height (or table height) when fonts are small

Tags: r, format, r-markdown, quarto, huxtable

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76269809/changing-table-height-with-huxtable-package-in-r-markdown) which was not answered...

I am using the Huxtable package in R to render tables in Quarto. You can use the `set_all_padding()` and `set_row_height()` functions to condense the height of the table by decreasing row (and column also) padding and heights, respectively.

In the example below, we can see that when you decrease font size, the cell contents seem too small for their rows. To get the same proportions as the first table, you'd need to further decrease row heights or padding, but the example seems to reach those functions' minimum settings for heights and padding.

**Question: Is there any way I can adjust the table to condense its height?**

````
---
# title: "test"
format: pdf
editor: source
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| message: false
library(huxtable)
library(magrittr)
```

```{r}
#| echo: false
ht <- huxtable(
        column1 = 1:5,
        column2 = letters[1:5]
      )
ht %>% 
        set_bottom_border(everywhere, value = 0.5) %>% 
        set_all_padding(everywhere, value = 0) %>% 
        set_row_height(everywhere, value = 0)
```


```{r}
#| echo: false
ht %>% 
        set_bottom_border(everywhere, value = 0.5) %>%
        set_all_padding(everywhere, value = 0) %>% 
        set_row_height(everywhere, value = 0) %>% 
        set_font_size(everywhere, value = 7)
```
````

[image: current output]